# Django - Social Auth (Request URL is showing http instead of https)

Tags: python, django, authentication, ssl, twitter-oauth

I have intergrated SSL certificate in my application and i have https in my site but in django social auth the Request URL goes only with http. 
I know the Twitter does not allow requests from http. Link : http://humbusy.tk/social-auth/login/twitter/

My site has https but the request goes with http .Why ? and How do i resolve it ? Thanks .

Comment: It shows `403 Client Error` did u set `clientid`, `client secret` properly?

Comment: well we have to  add consumer key and secret in our app right .? i have done it .

Comment: Select the Settings Tab in the Twitter application to configure the Callback URL, Add this `https://humbusy.tk/complete/twitter/`

Comment: Done.. Same results .

Comment: Try To Restart server once check or follow this  [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)

Comment: when i added google+ in my site it gave me same error of request url: I figured it out that twitter allows only https request but since my request url does not have https in it. It is showing me forbidden error .

Comment: So basically all the clients giving same error right?, then might small error in callback or client credentials, please update the settings file of the Social Login Configuration with dummy values

Comment: all clients are giving same error with Request URL when i updated google's policy with My request url , google+ started working fine. Hence there is no problem with the credentials in settings.py. It is the REQUEST URL causing all this problem with http.

Comment: Then Do one Thing add Callback for both `https` and `http` like `https://humbusy.tk/complete/twitter/` and `http://humbusy.tk/complete/twitter/` first check with `google+` and try with `twitter`

Comment: still problem persists...

Comment: Remove old one and Try to add this `https://humbusy.tk/oauth/complete/twitter/` and `http://humbusy.tk/oauth/complete/twitter/` to callback url

Comment: still nothing .

Comment: how did u configure `urls.py` for `social-auth-app` did u add like this `url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social'))` or share what u add

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social'))
]

Comment: Remove old one and Try to add this `https://humbusy.tk/social-auth/complete/twitter/` and `http://humbusy.tk/social-auth/complete/twitter/`

Comment: It Worked .  I used your URL instead of mine . Thanks Alot  . U saved me.

Comment: If u want test it with localhost, u have add to that url also in callback url like `http://localhost:8000/social-auth/complete/twitter/`, basically u were telling 
 the client that once authentication is success, where should twitter redirect to handle next process, such us the place where we create session for user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Your `urls.py` looks follow.

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')) ]
```

u have add callback URL in the Twitter App Configuration like follow.

```
https://humbusy.tk/social-auth/complete/twitter/
http://humbusy.tk/social-auth/complete/twitter/
```